# Graphql type-graphql how to pass one array of objects mutation

Tags: node.js, graphql, typegraphql

I need to pass one array of objects, but says I have to specify the type of parameter I try this line of code. It's not working @Arg("products") products:[ReservationProduct]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask We need to see your code/GraphQL query. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Arg("products", type => [ReservationProduct]) products: ReservationProduct[]`